# Stop authentication at an early pipeline stage- unless going to /Login?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a `MessageHandler` to authenticate a user.

If a request is *not* containing a special header , I want to block it at the `MessageHandler` stage.

But if the user wants to go to the `Users/Login` method, he will probably have no header  (because he is not Login yet ).

The problem is that I don't want to block him at the `[authorize]` controller level.

It's pretty simple :

- If he doesn't have  the header and he is not on the way to login — BLOCK
- If he doesn't have  the header and he is   on the way to login — only then - ALLOW

**Question**

- 1) At the `MessaageHandler` stage , how can I know that he is on a way to do login ? ( NB : I don't mention the `{action}` in the route. e.g. :

--

```
 public class User :ApiController
 { 
   [HttpPost]
   public bool CheckLogin (....) //i'm not specifying action in the route
    {
    }
}
```

- 2) Looking at the command to read the header :

`AuthenticationHeaderValue auth = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;`

But - *Authorization != Authentication*.

So why does web api reference the authorization header as an  Authentication ?

Comment: Not sure this is an option as its a completely decoupled solution from you mentioned code/location. But you could fall back to an old fashioned HttpModule which checks on destination & header(s). Abort early by placing the logic in the 'pre' pipe.

Comment: @MarvinSmit this won't behave the same if you host the WebApi in a console ( for  example). your proposal is only under asp.net iis :-)

Comment: Hence my starting sentence; not sure it's an option. The logic places inside the MessageHandler location as answered by Darin seems to be the solution for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MessageHandler` executes before routing has occurred. So at this stage you don't know yet which controller action will be executed.

One possibility would be to check the verb and the path being requested and perform the custom verification based on that:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string path = request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery;
    if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post && path.StartsWith("/api/checklogin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Do not enforce the presence of the custom header
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    // Check for the presence of your custom header
}
```

> So why does web api reference the authorization header as an Authentication ?

At HTTP level, the header is called `Authorization`.

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe you are trying to reinvent the wheel while it is already there. You have `Autorize` and `AllowAnonymous` (for your `Login` action) and then you could have a custom authentication filter to read the header and set up the `Principal` for the request lifetime.
2. The reason for that is that the term *authorization header* has been always used in the context of HTTP header-based authentication. Someone who used the tern for the first time was probably not aware that *authentication header* would probably be slightly more appropriate.

Comment: 1) As I said , the authorization ( authorization filter) stage is too late . I can surely block it earlier. I don't think Im inventing the wheel. If it doesnt have a header , and he is not going to login , he has nothing to do here at the pipeline.......... 2) thanks

Comment: Why it is "too late"? What happens eariler you want to block?